# (index):551 Uncaught ReferenceError: validateText is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-channels

Just wondering if anyone could help me troubeshoot this error? I am currently working on building a chat application within Django.

When I try to send a message within my chat, I receive the following error within the console:

```
(index):551 Uncaught ReferenceError: validateText is not defined
```

Here's the code within my template file from where the error seems to be originating from:

```
        var msgP = document.createElement("p")
        msgP.innerHTML = validateText(msg)
        msgP.classList.add("msg-p")
        div1.appendChild(msgP)
```

Just to add in here - My knowledge of JQuery isn't the best, so I do apologise if this comes across as a silly question!

Any suggestions would be welcome! :-)

Comment: The function **`validateText`** is not defined. There is nothing more to say than the error says. We need more code than a part of 4 lines.

Comment: Hey NKSM, thanks for your response! I will update my response with the code from my template file.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are trying to **validate a message** coming either from a user or a server I couldn't tell, however. my suggestion is you either **create the function** where you supply your validation criteria, or **obliterate** the whole function thing and accept the message as it is ... ***remember*** do be careful of accepting raw text from the user that can lead to so many problems.

your modified code might look like this :

```js
 var msgP = document.createElement("p")
 msgP.innerHTML = msg
 msgP.classList.add("msg-p")
 div1.appendChild(msgP)
```